# How do variables defined in the condition are used as global variables?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I want to take out the ip value of all servers that match the `when` condition.

My `ansible-playbook` is as follows:

```
- name: Get all the servers with docker installed
  shell: docker -v
  failed_when: False
  register: docker_exists

- name: Get the server where docker is installed
  shell: echo "{{inventory_hostname}}"
  register: docker_ip
  when: "'Docker version 18.09.6' in docker_exists.stdout"
```

Tested, the `docker_ip` variable is not a global variable, but only on a machine that satisfies the condition of `"Docker version 18.09.6' in docker_exists.stdout"`, on a machine that does not satisfy this condition. Direct error, suggesting `The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'`, how can I use the `docker_ip` variable globally??

~~Now how do I get all the server ips with docker installed through `docker_exists`, and the server without docker installed? Must obtain the ip value that satisfies the condition~~

~~Or is there any other way to get all the ips that satisfy the `when` condition?~~

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of questions in your question, but here we go:

> how can I use the `docker_ip` variable globally??

There is no such thing as "globally" -- **all** variables in ansible are "host" variables

> Now how do I get all the server ips with docker installed through `docker_exists`, and the server without docker installed?

```
- name: declare discovered docker hosts
  set_fact:
    hosts_with_docker: >-
      {%- set results = [] -%}
      {%- for hn in groups["all"] -%}
      {%- if "Docker version" in hostvars[hn].get("docker_exists", {"stdout": ""}).stdout -%}
      {%- set _ = results.append(hn) -%}
      {%- endif -%}
      {%- endfor -%}
      {{ results }}
```

If you quite literally mean the IP, and not the `inventory_hostname`, the change `results.append(hn)` to `results.append(hostvars[hn].ansible_default_ipv4.address)`

> Or is there any other way to get all the ips that satisfy the when condition?

In general, no, because every `set_fact` (which `register:` is just a convenient shortcut) is *per host*, so looping over all hosts is the only way to "broadcast" that information in a playbook